# how fix artisan error ? UnexpectedValueException

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

when I want use PHP artisan, I have one error, it is : 
 [php artisan error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc6EX.png)

Comment: You have an error in your routes. Please post web.php

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because you have defined routes in your `routes/web.php` or `routes/api.php` file with invokable or resourceful controllers that don't exist yet. For example, this would throw an error if the `PhotoController` doesn't exist.

```php
Route::get('/test', 'PhotoController');
```

But this wouldn't.

```php
Route::get('/test', 'PhotoController@store');
```

So make sure your controllers are defined correctly. If you are specifying resourceful or invokable controllers, make sure to create them first.

Answer (score 0):

**Single Action Controllers**

> If you would like to define a controller that **only handles a single
>   action**, you may place a single `__invoke` method on the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

//...
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
//...

class Goo extends Controller
{

    public function __invoke()
    {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

> When registering routes for single action controllers, you do not need
>   to specify a method:

```
Route::get('Uri', 'Auth\Goo');
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#single-action-controllers)